# Different page title in mobile version

Tags: mobile, web

I've developed mobile version for my website. Every page in mobile version has the same title in original version. Search engines doesn't rank the pages with similar titles and different content for keyword. How can I solve this problem? I want to add " - Mobile Version" phrase in my mobile pages titles. Could it be useful? Help me please...

Comment: How are the titles specified? From db? Are your pages different files? How are you determining if the user is "mobile"?

Comment: Titles specified from db and i use 51Degree component to detect mobile users.

Comment: Don't really know what that is, but can't you change the page title on the mobile pages. What is your question? Are you asking how or if you should.

Comment: If I should change my title pages in mobile version how does it affect my seo?

Comment: So, you should probably read up more on google and mobile sites. I "believe" they had a way before to submit some of your pages as mobile and some as regular so only some show up in mobile search. That could be old news, I think it was in webmaster tools, but I don't remember. I think you should be more worried about your page content than just the titles. Google is pretty smart, and I don't think adding Mobile Version or not having it will change your SEO much.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34648

Here is a link to some webmasters information on mobile site maps. Google can differentiate between mobile sites, and regular ones. Keeping page titles the same shouldn't ding you. Read more in their webmasters tools section. Almost everything is always documented pretty clearly.